# Reading CSV file and writing a function using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to `pandas`, but trying to learn it, but I've to create a function for this using the library. I've a csv file `source.csv` with dummy data (link to the file: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/yqtveyYa)). The key columns in it are: `month, area, name, errors`. For each month, from `MY WORKS` in `area`, the below `works` should be filtered(?). For each work, the issues in `errors` column should be counted. If no error, 0 should be taken into account.

```
import pandas as pd

source_df = pd.read_csv('source.csv') # Sorry guys, don't know how to proceed from here

works = ['WORLD', 'P&G', 'PART D', 'BRIGHTS', 'NOTIFICATION',
         'OOP', 'ABCD', 'CHANNEL', 'KENNY DISPLAY', 'Migration']

months = ['January', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June']


# Expected output:
data = {'WORLD': {'categories': months,
                'series': [{
                    'name': 'Big Issue',
                    'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  # Number of Big Issues in those months
                    }, {
                    'name': 'Small Issue',
                    'data': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]  # Number of Small Issues in those months
                    }, {
                    'name': 'Monitoring',
                    'data': [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]  # Number of Monitorings in those months
                    }, {
                    'name': 'Improvement',
                    'data': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]  # Number of Improvements in those months
                    }]
                },
        'P&G': {'categories': months,
                'series': [{
                    'name': 'Big Issue',
                    'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                    }, {
                    'name': 'Small Issue',
                    'data': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
                    }, {
                    'name': 'Monitoring',
                    'data': [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
                    }, {
                    'name': 'Improvement',
                    'data': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
                    }]
                }      

    }
```

The dictionary output would be complete with the rest of the elements in `works`. Expected output shown above is for `WORLD` and `P&G` only.

Comment: `source_df.groupby(['month','area','division', 'errors']).errors.count()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/kyogesh/c7c2e3e16e9d9477cad3d6477bfc4bd4

Please have a look at the gist I've pasted here.
This will give you the results. From here you can format the data as per your requirement.